# export data from postgresql 15 terminal

Tags: postgresql, psql

I got a lot information from google that to export database from postgresql using sqlAdmin software, but couldn't found about how to use Postgres 15 terminal to export the database.

I try access into my psql environment as `psql` in the terminal.

Below command that was found from other site, but it didn't work for inside terminal(psql) or terminal(exist psql) .

```
$ pg_dump -U USERNAME DBNAME > dbexport.pgsq
```

Comment: What is the result when you enter that command?

Comment: `pg_dump` is not a [SQL command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html) nor a [psql meta command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS) - it's command line tool just like `psql` so you need to run it the same way you run `psql`

Comment: @ValerieParham-Thompson nothing response after the command.

Comment: Do you see a file named dbexport.pgsq in the directory where you ran the `pg_dump` command?